# Java hyperlink readtext

Tags: java, verification

I'm trying to read the name from a hyperlink and use the name to compare with another for verification.

EDIT:
This is what i currently have

```
String linkText = ####;

    for(int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {

        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
        options.add("nameLink");
        options.add("nameLink");
        options.add("nameLink");
        options.add("nameLink");
        options.add("nameLink");

        if (options.contains(linkText))
```

What i want is to get the name of the hyperlink
ALink = www.link.com
so i want ALINK to be sent to linkText to compare if the name is the same.

Comment: could you try and make your example more explicit? it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant that you have two URL's, then you can use [the `URL.toString()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), and then compare the two Strings using `String.equals()`.